# Optimization of multiple inner self-joins by unique key

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Say I have some table `X` with transactions, where `CUSTOMER_ID` is a primary key.

Also I have hundred of "features" (in terms of machine learning) i.e. text of queries on this table `X`. 
All these queries are like:

Query 1:

```
SELECT
X.CUSTOMER_ID,
WHEN(X.GENDER = "F" AND X.IS_PREGNANT = TRUE) THEN 1 OTHERWISE 0 AS WILL_BUY_FOR_KIDS
FROM X
```

Query xxx:

```
SELECT
X.CUSTOMER_ID,
WHEN(X.GENDER = "M" AND X.AVG_AMOUNT > 1000) THEN 1 OTHERWISE 0 AS RICH_DUDE
FROM X
```

The task is to produce table with all "features" calculated from `X` table.
So I need to create text of output query (programmatically) using texts of "feature" queries.
Something like:

```
SELECT
*
FROM SOME_QUERY_1
INNER JOIN SOME_QUERY_X
ON SOME_QUERY_1.CUSTOMER_ID = SOME_QUERY_X.CUSTOMER_ID
...
```

Such output query above could be extremely slow when inner self-joins hundreds of sub-queries.
Clearly, it would be cool if SQL engine will "rewrite" this query to something like (avoid joins):

```
SELECT
CUSTOMER_ID,
WHEN(X.GENDER = "F" AND X.IS_PREGNANT = TRUE) THEN 1 OTHERWISE 0 AS WILL_BUY_FOR_KIDS,
WHEN(X.GENDER = "M" AND X.AVG_AMOUNT > 1000) THEN 1 OTHERWISE 0 AS RICH_DUDE,
.....
FROM X
```

Few questions:

1. Is there any SQL engine that can make the optimization above (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)?
2. With common numerical algebra we have proven rules to simplify expressions (for example: `(a + b) * a = a^2 + b*a`). Are there such rules for relational algrebra?

Comment: What is the purpose of these subqueries?

Comment: BTW: postgres is smart enough to collapse the subqueries, but it does not detect that x1.* and x2.* refer to the same tuple. Result is a merge join on two index scans.

Comment: @wildplasser I've updated the description to add more context to the question

Comment: Please don't update the question, it will make the existing answer look silly (which it is not). Instead, put the new material into a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Oracle's optimizer does the work.

```
drop table x;
create table x (a int primary key,b int);

select  x0.b,x1.b,x2.b,x3.b,x4.b,x5.b,x6.b,x7.b,x8.b,x9.b

from         (select x.a,x.b from x) x0
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x1 on x1.a = x0.a
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x2 on x2.a = x0.a
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x3 on x3.a = x0.a
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x4 on x4.a = x0.a
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x5 on x5.a = x0.a
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x6 on x6.a = x0.a
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x7 on x7.a = x0.a
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x8 on x8.a = x0.a
        join (select x.a,x.b from x) x9 on x9.a = x0.a
;
```

Note the 9 **ELIMINATE_JOIN** in the execution plan.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| X    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------      

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):                   
-------------------------------------------------------------                   

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$44564B95 / X@SEL$2                                                   

Outline Data                                                                    
-------------                                                                   

  /*+                                                                           
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA                                                        
      FULL(@"SEL$44564B95" "X"@"SEL$2")                                         
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$3")                                                         
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")                                                         
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")                                                         
      MERGE(@"SEL$3")                                                           
      MERGE(@"SEL$2")                                                           
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$5428C7F1")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$5")                                                         
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$4")                                                         
      MERGE(@"SEL$5428C7F1")                                                    
      MERGE(@"SEL$5")                                                           
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$730B2DEF")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$7")                                                         
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$6")                                                         
      MERGE(@"SEL$730B2DEF")                                                    
      MERGE(@"SEL$7")                                                           
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$DE510E9C")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$9")                                                         
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$8")                                                         
      MERGE(@"SEL$DE510E9C")                                                    
      MERGE(@"SEL$9")                                                           
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$6C54F645")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$11")                                                        
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$10")                                                        
      MERGE(@"SEL$6C54F645")                                                    
      MERGE(@"SEL$11")                                                          
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$5E3B1022")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$13")                                                        
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$12")                                                        
      MERGE(@"SEL$5E3B1022")                                                    
      MERGE(@"SEL$13")                                                          
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$D60B40D8")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$15")                                                        
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$14")                                                        
      MERGE(@"SEL$D60B40D8")                                                    
      MERGE(@"SEL$15")                                                          
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$B8655000")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$17")                                                        
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$16")                                                        
      MERGE(@"SEL$B8655000")                                                    
      MERGE(@"SEL$17")                                                          
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$EC740ABE")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$19")                                                        
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$18")                                                        
      MERGE(@"SEL$EC740ABE")                                                    
      MERGE(@"SEL$19")                                                          
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$7AC5A3AA")                                                  
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$20")                                                        
      MERGE(@"SEL$7AC5A3AA")                                                    
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$F6D45FB3")                                                  
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$F6D45FB3" "X"@"SEL$17")                              
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$F6D45FB3" "X"@"SEL$15")                              
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$F6D45FB3" "X"@"SEL$13")                              
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$F6D45FB3" "X"@"SEL$11")                              
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$F6D45FB3" "X"@"SEL$9")                               
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$F6D45FB3" "X"@"SEL$7")                               
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$F6D45FB3" "X"@"SEL$5")                               
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$F6D45FB3" "X"@"SEL$3")           
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$5A225B26")                                                  
      ELIMINATE_JOIN(@"SEL$5A225B26" "X"@"SEL$19")                              
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$44564B95")                                             
      ALL_ROWS                                                                  
      DB_VERSION('11.2.0.2')                                                    
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('11.2.0.2')                                     
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS                                               
      END_OUTLINE_DATA                                                          
  */                                                                            

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):                     

   1 - "X"."B"[NUMBER,22]                                                       

Note                                                                            
-----                                                                           
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Comment: Cool.
Most interesting thing - is ELIMINATE_JOIN stage common among other SQL engines? Are there any proven relational rules that can do that trick OR it is a "hack"?

Comment: Hi Lars :-) These question are way too broad. There is a long distance between the theory to the implementation of each  specific provider.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should write the query as:

```
SELECT X1.A * 2, // Some operation on X1.A
       X2.B / 2 // Some operation on X2.B
FROM X X1 JOIN
     X X2
     ON X1.C = X2.C;
```

The subqueries provide no value (but I'll return to that later).

If `C` is declared as `unique` (or `primary key`), then there is an index on the field.  I'm pretty sure every database will still do the `JOIN`, but it will be really fast:

- Process a record (`X1`) and find `C`
- Lookup `C` in an index
- Return to the record already in memory to get `X2`.

The additional overhead for going through an index is not a big burden, compared to reading the data in the first place.

With the query as you have written it, most databases are smart enough to still do this optimization -- they just ignore the subquery.  MySQL is an exception.  It actually materializes subqueries, so the version you have written is likely to be pathetically slow -- the materialization loses the ability to use indexes as well.  However, the re-write should be fine.

You might ask why databases don't have an optimization for this.  Well, database developers are more focused on optimizing well-written queries than on optimizing poorly written ones.  If there is no need for the `JOIN`, then the query write should be aware of that.  (Actually, the `JOIN` does have one use, it filters out `NULL` values.)

Comment: The main problem is exactly to avoid multiple inner self-joins by primary key.
I've updated the description to add more context to the question.